# Android - Imageview in listview how to reduce the lag?

Tags: android, image, listview, imageview

I'm coding an app with android studio. This is a todolists manager in which you can also add images.

I have a Listview containing items with an ImageView in each. But when there are images to display the listview scrolls really slowly and the app lag.

I saw that I need to do something on a separate thread but how can I do this exactly ?

My app uses MVP and I create the listview with an adapter that extends "BaseAdapter" and uses "setURI" to put the image into the ImageView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this answer will help u
Of course u have to use separate thread.
U can use imageloader libraries for that according to ur need

Below are libraries link choose which u want to use:

1. Glide:
   https://github.com/bumptech/glide[enter link description here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)
2. Picasso:https://github.com/square/picasso[enter link description here](https://github.com/square/picasso)
3. Universal image loader:
   https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader[enter link description here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)

Now which to choose
I personally recommend glide.if u want to load big size image than go with universal image loader,if u want to go with small images than go with picasso

Hope this answer help u..if u want any other help u can ask for it

Comment: I tried with Picasso and it worked but it's still slow... The pictures take a little more time to load but it still freezes when I scroll :/

Comment: Can u please post ur adapter code here?may be there is another reason for lagging

Comment: Yes I found it, it was because I wasn't resizing the images with .fit()... Now i do :)... But I'd like to resize them and keeping the proportions, is it possible with picasso ?

Comment: Oh, once again, this wasn't hard :p... .centerInside()

Comment: I recommend to use resize(width,height) it will reduce image size also

Answer (score 0):

Use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to image in a imageview. It uses Automatic memory and disk caching. Hope it will fasten the scrolling.

Just one line of code to load image to **ImageView**.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imageView1);
```

Comment: I tried it but it does not display my image...
In my adapter : Picasso.with(context).load(Uri.parse(elements.get(position).getImage())).into(iv);

(Where "iv" is my image view and element.getImage returns the path)

Comment: use getApplicationContext() instead of contex. And check your image path correctly.

Comment: It doesn't work, same with glide... That's weird, because I didn't change anything in the URI, it's the same thing than before. My old code was : "iv.setImageURI(Uri.parse(elements.get(position).getImage()));" and it worked.

Comment: what picasso version you are using? @MBek

Comment: 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

Comment: where are the image files stored?

Comment: These are image from the sdcard (that the user can choose from the galery).

Comment: Maybe it's because i use a "Base Adapter" ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Libraries that optimized to load images like Glide or Picasso. another way is to use a compressed version of images as thumbnail and load the original image when you're showing details of your list item

Answer (score 0):

Use 9 patch images . It will customize the images for every resolution. Sometimes it lags because image resolution is different from your screen resolution.